# Has there ever been a leak of a movie or TV show's entire project data?

Tags: film-industry

There have been and will be leaks of movies and TV shows, but I'm interested in whether there has ever been a leak of an entire project. By this, I mean the leaking of a folder with terabytes of data, such as takes, sounds, effects, scripts, maybe some organizational files, that kind of stuff, like when the source code of a game gets leaked.

I don't know how movies are organized digitally, and maybe that kind of leak is impossible, but if it is possible, has it ever happened?

Comment: [Sony Pictures Hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Pictures_hack)

Comment: @Rahul What movie was leaked? The link without explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: @MeatTrademark: It was a very famous leak. Movies like Fury, Anne etc. This is not a complete answer in itself, that's why only direction to link.

Comment: Is the question if any finished product was leaked, or ALL the data (individual scenes, different takes, sound mixes, the stuff used to MAKE the finished product)?

Comment: @MeatTrademark Later. Maybe not all, but something other than finished product.